# loop and change the first letter of file

Tags: python, os.walk

i have about 300 files in a folder in which the first line is 1, i would like to change it to 0,

this is the piece of code i'm using to get it done

```
import os


for root,dirs,files in os.walk('/home/decentmakeover2/try/'):
for file in files:

    if file.endswith('.txt'):
        with open(file, 'r+b') as f:
            line = next(f) # grab first line
            old = '1'
            new = '0' 
            f.seek(0) 
            f.write(line.replace(old, new))
```

but i get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "one.py", line 8, in <module>
with open(file, 'r+b') as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'yield_021.txt'
```

but the thing is the file is present in the folder and its just like the other files,if i delete the file then i get the same error but with a different filename

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `os.path.join`, and join your root with your filename, since `open` needs the fully qualified path to work.

```
with open(os.path.join(root, file), ...) as f:
```

Where `root` is the first value returned by `os.walk`.

Comment: This is         Perfect!

Comment: ill have to wait 10 more min before i can accept it

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to check each file's first character and if it's '1' then it will change it to '0' and rewrite the txt file.

```
import os , re
path = r'the path of your file'

with os.scandir(path) as directory:
for item in directory:
 if not item.name.startswith('.') and item.is_file():
   with open(item, mode="r+") as file:
      line = file.readlines()
      if len(line) != 0:
        if line[0][0] == '1':
          line = line[0].replace("1", "0", 1)     
          contents = file.read().split("\n")
          file.seek(0) 
          file.truncate()
          file.write(line)

file.close()
```

Comment: Why give another answer after 6y, even if there is already an accepted answer?

Comment: because I tried the other one and I think mine is better. First, I didn't notice when it was posted. Second, I'm a new developer trying to be more active on Stack overflow and you're demotivating people like me!

Comment: i guess opinions differ. but i wish you the best in your journey!